# Cumulatively add values to Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

I am trying to add values to a dictionary as they get determined based on certain conditions. The app has to loop through each line and once a certain condition has been met then a value must be added to the dictionary. Here is the code that is task with looping through the lines and determine values to be added.

```
  foreach (var line in this.FileLines)
    {
        count++;

        string[] bits = line.Split(',');
        fineNumber = bits[0].Trim();
        int length = bits.Length;
        if (length == 9)
        {
            //other processing gets done here, code not included as its of no interest for this question
        }
        else
        {
            //AddErrorFinesToFile(line, fineNumber);
            AddFinesToDictonary(fineNumber, line);
            continue;
        }
    }
```

Then below is the actual method signature and its code, in this method I am simply trying to add values to the dictionary as they come.

```
public Dictionary<string, string> AddFinesToDictonary(string fineNumber, string errorLine)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> erroredLines = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        erroredLines.Add(fineNumber, errorLine);
        return erroredLines;
    }
```

The only problem that seems to arise here is, only the latest value gets added to the dictionary, meaning the previous added value gets overwritten.

Comment: No the fine  numbers are not the same, every fine gets it own unique number, this fines actual come from a csv file and they're all unique

Comment: You don't even save the retuned dictionary. In the `foreach` loop you have no longer access to the errorLines dictionary.

Comment: You could just do this one-line: `Dictionary<string, string> fines = this.FileLines.Select(line => new { line, bits = line.Split(',') }).Where(x => x.bits.Length == 9).ToDictionary(x => x.bits[0].Trim(), x => x.line);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make erroredLines as global scope.

```
Dictionary<string, string> erroredLines = new Dictionary<string, string>();

foreach (var line in this.FileLines)
    {
        count++;

        string[] bits = line.Split(',');
        fineNumber = bits[0].Trim();
        int length = bits.Length;
        if (length == 9)
        {
            //other processing gets done here, code not included as its of no interest for this question
        }
        else
        {
            //AddErrorFinesToFile(line, fineNumber);
            AddFinesToDictonary(fineNumber, line);
            continue;
        }
    }




public void AddFinesToDictonary(string fineNumber, string errorLine)
    {
               erroredLines.Add(fineNumber, errorLine);
       // return erroredLines;
    }
```

And also no need to return erroredLines dictionary.

Comment: There are no global variables in C#.

Comment: @Enigmativity corrected as per your comment ,what  do you call the variables of global scope in c#

Comment: There are no global variables in C#. There are no variables of global scope. All variables are defined within classes.

Comment: @Enigmativity You have to read “global“ as defined as outside of the `foreach` loop and therewith not inside the method `AddFinesToDictonary` of the question. Wording is not precise, but IMHO one can get what Hameed wanted to express.

Comment: @VolkerMilbrandt - Yes, that's fair enough.

Answer (score 1):

What about this;

```
 Dictionary<string, string> erroredLines = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    foreach (var line in this.FileLines)
        {
            count++;

            string[] bits = line.Split(',');
            fineNumber = bits[0].Trim();
            int length = bits.Length;
            if (length == 9)
            {
                //other processing gets done here, code not included as its of no interest for this question
            }
            else
            {

                erroredLines.Add(fineNumber, line);
                continue;
            }
        }
```

after foreach you can use erroredLines dictionary.

Comment: I have done that already, though I think you meant "inside" foreach instead of "after", the addition of the value has to be inside the foreach because you'd want to add values as and when they get picked up as the code does its loop. Your comment does add value indeed

Comment: you can add values to erroredLines dictionary inside foreach. Finish foreach use whole erroredLines dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is every time you add data to the Directory you create a new one instead of adding data to the exists one

There are two choices you could make:

1. make a Dictionary out of the function
2. pass the Dictionary as an `out` ref to the function

@Hameed Syed 's answer has already given the first one (option 1).

Here is how you could pass the Dictionary as a ref parameter (`out`) to the function (option 2):

```
public void AddFinesToDictonary(out Dictionary<string,string>dict, string fineNumber, string errorLine)
{
    dict.Add(fineNumber, errorLine);          
}
```

Comment: This is not an answer; it's more like a comment.